# Log non-delivery reports sent out from my environment

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

I'm wanting to log non-delivery reports sent out from my environments. I can't find any place where they are logged specifically.

Is it possible to gather info about them (going forward) such as datetime, recipient, and smtp code.

Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2013.

Comment: Do you mean Non-delivery reports?

Comment: @music2myear Yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand how the construct works. If the email left your MS Exchange environment, then you do no longer have the option to "track" it, as its no longer your environment.

If the NDR bounce, you can check the header from the bounce email for the mailflow and which server did what, but only when you have that.

Comment: Sorry, "log" would be a better word than track. Edited question for clarification